# No account in openshift has cluster-administration privileges.

Tags: openshift-origin

I have a fresh install of openshift and I am logged in with credentials system:admin(via oc). When I try to get the list of the routers, I get this:

```
[root@centos2 master]# oadm router --dry-run     --credentials='/etc/openshift/master/openshift-router.kubeconfig'     --service-account=router
Flag --credentials has been deprecated, use --service-account to specify the service account the router will use to make API calls
error: can't check for existing router "router": User "system" cannot get services in project "default"
```

I also can not add a new router and get information about the services. I have tried with other users, too. I guess that it is a privileges related issue. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logged in as "system", which is not the same as "system:admin".  The former has no permissions by default.

```
oc login -u system:admin
```

Should ensure you are the right user.